# how to append database records in to a variable in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I fetched all users from the database based on city name.

**Here is my code:**

```
@othertask = User.find(:all, :conditions => { :city => params[:city]})
@othertask.each do |o|
  @other_tasks = Micropost.where(:user_id => o.id).all 
end
```

My problem is when loop gets completed, `@other_task` holds only last record value.

Is it possible to append all ids record in one variable?

Comment: use `map` on `@othertask`

Comment: The naming is very confusing. Why are you calling an array of users `@othertask` when it is neither a task nor a single object?

Comment: +1 Agree that the naming choices are extremely confusing. Why not `@users` and `@posts`?

Comment: `@other_task` is holding the last record value or `@other_tasks` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it by following way

```
 @othertask = User.find(:all, :conditions => { :city => params[:city]})
 @other_tasks =  Array.new 
 @othertask.each do |o|
   @other_tasks << Micropost.where(:user_id => o.id).all 
 end
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but you are not using temp variable anywhere.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting so many upvotes. This is absolutely the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You should be using a join for something like this, rather than looping and making N additional queries, one for each user. As you now have it, your code is first getting *all* users with a given city attribute value, then for each user you are *again* querying the DB to get a micropost (`Micropost.where(:user_id => o.id)`). That is extremely inefficient.

You are searching for all microposts which have a user whose city is `params[:city]`, correct? Then there is no need to first find all users, instead query the microposts table directly:

```
@posts = Micropost.joins(:user).where('users.city' => params[:city])
```

This will find you all posts whose user has a `city` attribute which equals `params[:city]`.

p.s. I would strongly recommend reading the [Ruby on Rails guide on ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more details on how to use associations effectively.

Comment: To add - We also need an association in models for that query to get work.

Comment: True, I assumed that the presence of `user_id` on the `Micropost` model meant that a there was a `belongs_to` association defined.

Comment: That's good to hear. Please read the Rails guide on associations for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code:

```
@othertask = User.find_all_by_city(params[:city])
@other_tasks = Array.new  
@othertask.each do |o|
  @other_tasks << Micropost.find_all_by_user_id(o.id)
end
```

You are only getting the last record because of using '=' operator, instead you need to use '<<' operator in ruby which will append the incoming records in to the array specified.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

User model:

```
has_many :microposts
```

Micropost model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

Query

```
@Microposts = Micropost.joins(:user).where('users.city' => params[:city])
```